# Generic Bit Macros

Tags: macros, bitwise-operators, glibc, bit, netbsd

I'm looking for generic bit macros (e.g. extracting or setting multiple bits), so that I don't have to reinvent them. On NetBSD I found at least `__BIT` and `__BITS` in `<sys/cdefs.h>`, but glibc doesn't seem to have such macros (though GCC provides some more complex built-in bit functions). I haven't looked into other platforms yet. Does anyone know other predefined bit macros or functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there're none on MS (except the trivial HIWORD/LOWORD, etc) but on the other hand, why not use bit fields instead? If you have to deal with bits having a predefined layout, that is.